# how to express a permutation in transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra

$(1,5,2)(3)(4,7)(6)$.

How can i determine whether this permutation is even or odd ?

$(1,5,2)$ can be written as $(1,2)(1,5)$ and $(4,7)$ is already a transposition but what about $(3)$ and $(6)$. How can we express them as transpositions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the convention is to just omit them:
$$
(1, 2)(1, 5)(4, 7)
$$
If this bothers you, then you can always replace it with two repeated transpositions. For example:
$$
(3) = (1,3)(1,3)
$$

Comment: That makes perfect sense , thanks alot